# Does Critical Damage Carry Over to Secondary Enemies in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In-game I have noticed what appears to be a carry-over of damage on a second enemy after a critical hit one the first enemy. I'm thinking it might just be a coincidence, but if it is a coincidence, it seems to be a very common one. However, I have been unable to verify one way or the other if crit-damage carries over or not. This [article](http://falloutsheltercheatcodes.blogspot.com/2016/09/4-awesome-tips-to-completing-quests-in.html) mentions critical hits, but only says to take advantage of them and explains that they do increased damage to the targeted enemy. Likewise, this [tip list](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-02-07-fallout-shelter-quests-combat-tips-daily-quests-more-4798) mentions critical hits, but does not discuss whether the damage carries over. I had hoped that Bethesda's forum question "[How Does Quest Combat Work in Fallout Shelter?](https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/34936/~/how-does-quest-combat-work-in-fallout-shelter%3F)" would lead to better insights, but it was the most vague of the three. So the question remains: **Does Critical Damage Carry Over to Secondary Enemies in Fallout Shelter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not carry over damage.  That's your dweller shooting right after a crit.

This is very noticeable with the Fat Man.  If you wait until you launched a Fat Man and then trigger the crit, you'll immediately launch a second time.